# Retrieving the Last Date Entry for Multiple IDs

Tags: sql

I am trying to return the last date a user has logged in, for each user ID. Below is my code. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

```
SELECT name, userid, attemptdate, attemptresult
FROM [logintracking]
WHERE attemptresult = 'login' 
ORDER BY userid ASC
```

Comment: Please, always put the query you're trying as plain text. Results can be pasted as well. Avoid screenshots. Also, add the tag related to the database engine you're using, as it would matter in the way to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the user and use `max()` to get the highest date for each one

```
select userid, name, max(attemptdate)
from logintracking
group by userid, name
order by userid asc
```